# Create an owned wrapper around a struct with borrowed parameters in new()

Tags: rust

I wish to use an external `struct` ([Framer](https://docs.rs/embedded-websocket/0.8.0/embedded_websocket/framer/struct.Framer.html#method.new)) which `&'a mut` borrows a number of parameters in its `new()` method. This is a problem when I insert an instance of the struct in a HashMap with a larger scope. I understand why.

I wrapped the offending `struct` in my own `struct` in an attempt to overcome the problem - but again ran into ownership problems. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9dd57d0ce53d28b8d70bf8c0d69c89b8)

```
struct Owned<'b> {
    buf: Box<[u8]>,
    foo: Option<Foo<'b>>,
}

impl<'b> Owned<'b> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut owned = Self {
            buf: Box::new([0; 1000]),
            foo: None,
        };
        owned.foo = Some(Foo::new(&mut *owned.buf));
        owned
        /*
        ^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
        ^^^^^ returning this value requires that `*owned.buf` is borrowed for `'a`
        */
    }
}
```

I understand why returning `owned` exposes the borrowed `buf`. But, I feel that I should be able link the lifetime of owned.buf to owned.foo - but I cannot see how.

I would like to know:

1. How to wrap Foo in Owned successfully
2. Or alternatively, some better way to insert Foo in a HashMap from a larger scope.

Comment: Thank you - but I have worked thru that answer - and still do not know how to proceed. If fact I thought that I was attempting to "Place types that own data into a structure together and then provide methods that allow you to get references or objects containing references as needed." but could not quite make it work

Comment: In your case it means constructing the `Foo` instance on-the-fly. Is `Foo::new()` expensive? If not, it may be a viable approach. In general, we would need more details to come with a concrete solution.

Comment: Unfortunately yes - `Foo::new()` is expensive. In the real-world case  `Framer::new()` is followed by `Framer::connect()` which negotiates the setup of an enduring WebSocket. `Framer` is then stored in a HashMap for later retrieval and message processing.

Comment: What is the error when stored in the map?

Comment: As per the Playground link above - the HashMap.insert() is fine - but the  HashMap.get() fails with `borrowed value does not live long enough` in the outer scope.

Comment: It seems then that the answer is that this cannot be done in rust.

This is a good answer because I learned a lot about rust trying to get this done. I was not missing some silly thing as I feared. (clearly I am still missing plenty - this is rust right!)

So, the next question is: why was Framer designed in such an annoying way? And it turns out (with a little digging past the examples and into the code) that I was doing it wrong. And (as Chayim Friedman enquired) it is cheap to create a Framer (the cost is elsewhere), and a modest code redesign is in order.

Thank you StackOverflow :-)

Comment: @nhoj Note that it _is_ possible but you have to use `unsafe` and know what you're doing.